# value is not updating in useEffect of reactjs hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**Here my code in Reactjs Function:**

```
const [reRender, setReRender] = React.useState(false);

let price = 10;

const changePrice = (value) => {
    price = value;
    console.log('price now', price);

    setReRender(!reRender);
};
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('re render happend');
    console.log('final price now', price);
}, [reRender]);
```

So, I use this code inside **Reactjs** function. In 1st render, I got `console.log('final price now', price);` is 10, which is for `let price = 10`. After that, when I call `changePrice` function with value 15, then I got `console.log('price now', price);` is 15 and also re-render happend but now I got again 10 for `console.log('final price now', price);`.

How can I got 15 after re-render? Or can I implement any async/await to get it? How?

Please help..

Comment: That is what `useState` is for. When the component re-renders, the function (functional component) is called again and in the new context, `price` was never changed.

Comment: @Titus, How can I got my desire solution sir?

Comment: Keep track of the price using a state variable (`const [price, setPrice] = React.useState()`). Also, is not a good idea to define functions inside the component like you've did for `changePrice`. Use something like `const changePrice = React.useCallback((value) => {setPrice(value); setReRender(!reRender);}, [reRender])`

Comment: Sir, I can't use price as a state, because state can be change by user from browser, but here my price came from database, I can't set it on state... Is there any possible solution without using state? @Titus

Comment: Perhaps you forgot that `setState` takes an initial variable then?

Comment: I use props for initial variable @AdamAzad

Comment: If security is the concern, using a `price` variable like that won't make things more secure than using a `state` property.

Comment: Then how can I make more secure `price` variable which can't change using react devtools when I use `state` property? @Titus

Comment: You can't, security should be done on the server. Make it so it won't matter if the price is changed on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

```
let [price, setPrice] = useState(10);
const changePrice = (value) => {
setPrice(value);
console.log('price now', price);
setReRender(!reRender);
};
```